# Computation Error in CodingBat exercise

Tags: python

I seem to have made a computation error in my Python code but am not quite sure what caused it. I think it may be due to having two 'and' operators in my if statement but I wanted to ask on Stack Overflow to be sure.

Here is the question:

**Given 2 int values, return True if one is negative and one is positive. Except if the parameter "negative" is True, then return True only if both are negative.**

Here is my code:

```
def pos_neg(a, b, negative):
  if a < 0 and b > 0 and negative = False:
    return True
  elif a > 0 and b < 0 and negative = False:
    return True
  elif a < 0 and b < 0 and negative = True:
    return True
```

Here is the correct answer:

```
def pos_neg(a, b, negative):
  if negative:
    return (a < 0 and b < 0)
  else:
    return ((a < 0 and b > 0) or (a > 0 and b < 0))
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Your problem is that you use an assigment `=` where you should be using an equality check `==` (except you shouldn't explicitly be doing that either)

Comment: You have to use `==` for checking if things are equal, **not** `=`

Comment: You also don't return a boolean value for every case (what happens if `a` > 0, `b` > 0 and `negative` is true?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without explicitly writing the solution for you (which I guess would be pointless anyway because the one from the answer book looks about as good as possible), there are two errors worth pointing out that should set you along the right track:

- Python equality checks are done using `==`, **not** `=`; the latter is the assignment operator and will result in a `SyntaxError` in that context.

  - Also, it's not good style to explicitly compare boolean variables to boolean constants. It's like someome asking you "Is 'it is raining' true?" instead of just "Is it raining?" At my university one of the professors would dock us 10,000 marks for writing code like that (at least he said that).
- There are certain paths in your implementation that will result in `None` being returned instead of a boolean `True` or `False`. This is bad practice because it makes your function less intuitive to use by clients and could catch them out. Consider if `a > 0` and `b > 0` and `negative` is `True`.

For what it's worth, there's nothing wrong with having multiple `and` or `or` operators within a conditional expression, although you should be aware of their [short-circuiting behaviour](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not).

Answer (score 0):

After changing '=' to '==' and adding an else statement, I was able to get the correct answer. Here is my new code:

```
def pos_neg(a, b, negative): 

    if a < 0 and b > 0 and negative == False: 
        return True 
    elif a > 0 and b < 0 and negative == False: 
        return True 
    elif a < 0 and b < 0 and negative == True: 
        return True 
    else: 
        return False
```

However, I'm a little confused about your explanations of boolean constants and variables. Would it be possible for one of you to simplify your explanations? I'm still new to Python and programming in general so it was hard to grasp at first glance.